# Unknown column 'users' in 'where clause' in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to fix this error. I am using Rails 4

```
Mysql2::Error at /projects/aof_southwest

Unknown column 'users' in 'where clause'
```

In my projects_controller.rb

```
    def show
        if params[:jump]
          # try to redirect to the requested menu item
          redirect_to_project_menu_item(@project, params[:jump]) && return
        end

        @users_by_role = @project.users_by_role
        @subprojects = @project.children.visible.all
        @news = @project.news.includes(:author, :project).order("#{News.table_name}.created_on DESC").limit(5)
        @trackers = @project.rolled_up_trackers
  end

# Returns a hash of project users grouped by role
  def users_by_role
    members.includes(:user, :roles).inject({}) do |h, m|
      m.roles.each do |r|
        h[r] ||= []
        h[r] << m.user
      end
      h
    end
  end
```

project.rb

```
has_many :members, -> { where("#{User.table_name}.type='User' AND #{User.table_name}.status=#{User::STATUS_ACTIVE}").includes(:principal, :roles)}
```

The column is exists in Mysql. But am getting

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users' in 'where clause': SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`project_id` = 117 AND (users AND users.status=1)
```

Please help me to fix error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Unknown column 'users' in 'where clause': SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`project_id` = 117 AND (users AND users.status=1)
```

This error suggests that you are trying to search members in USER table:

Try something like:

```
Member.where(:type=> 'User',:status => "{User::STATUS_ACTIVE}").includes(:principal, :roles)
```